# Is there a way to deactivate Buffer overflow protection on my machine?

Tags: linux, security, gcc

I want to do some experiments with buffer overflows on my various virtual machines, including (but not limited to) Debian 6, Ubuntu 12.04, Fedora 16, but every time I try to execute the buffer overflow exploit I get the following message:

```
stack smashing detected (core dumped)
```

After doing my research I read that it is a feature called **buffer overflow protection** implemented in the compiler. **GCC** for instance uses **GCC Stack-Smashing Protector (ProPolice)**, **Clang/LLVM** uses **two buffer overflow detectors, SafeCode and AddressSanitizer**.

My question is: Since I really want to check out buffer overflow attacks ***on my machines*** is there a way (a compiler flag, perhaps? a linux config file?) to deactivate the buffer overflow protection?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### GCC

On gcc (`man gcc`) the checks are enabled by

> ```
>   -fstack-protector
>       Emit extra code to check for buffer overflows, such as stack smashing attacks.  >This is done by adding a guard variable to functions with
>       vulnerable objects.  This includes functions that call alloca, and functions with >buffers larger than 8 bytes.  The guards are initialized when
>       a function is entered and then checked when the function exits.  If a guard check >fails, an error message is printed and the program exits.
>
>   -fstack-protector-all
>       Like -fstack-protector except that all functions are protected.
> ```

You can disable both by prepending `no-` to the option name

```
-fno-stack-protector -fno-stack-protector-all
```

### LLVM/Clang

On LLVM/Clang (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#commandline) to enable/disable AdressSanitizer:

> -f[no-]address-sanitizer: Turn on AddressSanitizer, a memory error detector.

and SAFECode (http://safecode.cs.illinois.edu/docs/UsersGuide.html)

> -f[no-]memsafety

Comment: Is there a (simple) way to detect, whether a program has been compiled with SSP?

Comment: @Michuelnik you could see if the binary contains any reference to `__stack_chk_fail` (e.g., `strings /bin/mybinary | grep __stack_chk_fail`

Comment: i just tested it with GCC 4.7 and 4.1: option `-fno-stack-protector-all` is not recognized (`-fstack-protector`, `-fstack-protector-all` and `-fno-stack-protector` are recognized)

Comment: `gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fno-stack-protector-all’; did you mean ‘-fstack-protector-all’?`

Comment: Clang 11. The flag is now `-f[no-]sanitize=address`